# PHP locale framework for alternative to native locale system (like setlocale)

Tags: php, locale

I always had a problem that translate English date to Thai. When server not support localization, it must be problem that i can't use date() function properly.

So, is there any framework or best practice to handle with server that don't have our locale installed. For now, I use workaround by hardcode map English text <=> Thai text.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the PHP library [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Example:

```
$d = new DateTime($myLATimeStampString, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Oslo'));
$time = $d->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```